# C# PdfPKCS7 VerifySignature fails

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, digital-signature, x509certificate

I am trying to read attributes from the digital certificate in C# for several digital signed PDF files.

In the same program, when I call for the first time to the function VerifySignature, it works and i can get the signature details. However, when i try to do it for a second time it fails.

```
PdfReader readerX = new PdfReader(@"Z:\cert\PDF\fdo.pdf");
AcroFields af = readerX.AcroFields;
ArrayList names = af.GetSignatureNames();

for (int i = 0; i < names.Count; ++i)
{
  string name = (string)names[i];
  PdfPKCS7 pk = af.VerifySignature(name); // It works
  MessageBox.Show(pk.SignName);
}

PdfReader readerX2 = new PdfReader(@"Z:\cert\PDF\fdo2.pdf");
AcroFields af2 = readerX2.AcroFields;
ArrayList names2 = af2.GetSignatureNames();

for (int i = 0; i < names2.Count; ++i)
{
   String name = (string)names2[i];
   PdfPKCS7 pk2 = af2.VerifySignature(name); // System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException exception
   MessageBox.Show(pk2.SignName);
}
```

I am using different variables, and the files are identical (fdo2.pdf is a copy from fdo.pdf) and both have the same digital signature. Do I need to "free" in some way the first instance of PdfPKCS7 to be able to reuse the functionality?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: In fact, if I change the order (fdo2.pdf in first place and fdo.pdf in second place), it only works for fdo2.pdf and fails in verifySignature for fdo.pdf. Or if i read the files  in separated programs, they both work

Comment: First of all, which iText(Sharp) version do you use? It obviously is not 7.x but it does not appear to be a current 5.5.x, either, because `af2.GetSignatureNames()` returns a `List<string>`, not an `ArrayList`. Changing these types in your code, though, it executes just fine, no problem verifying the second document's signatures.

Comment: Thank you, @mkl. Where i can check the version? In the references properties for itextsharp dll i can see: version: 3.1.0.0 . Is that the version that you mean?  I have tried to change ArrayList to List<String>, but it fails to compile because the method GetsignatureNames expects ArrayList

Comment: iTextSharp 3.1 is ancient (release date 2006-03-03). Apparently since that version some return types have been made less specific (e.g. `ArrayList` to `List<String>` here) and some bugs have been fixed (e.g. the issue you observe). You should consider updating at least to 4.2.0.0 (latest non-AGPL version), better to 5.5.13.0 (latest somewhat compatible version), and yet even better to 7.1.5.0 (completely re-vamped API; currently actively maintained branch). Unfortunately the better the update target, the more changes to your code will be necessary.

Comment: Thank you @mkl, yes. It is really ancient. I will explore the impact on updating to the mentioned versions. Thank you again, it was very helpful